# Wrapping of multiline text in TextView - Android

Tags: android

I have a multiline TextView with a layout_width="wrap_content" property. The problem is when
the TextView actually becomes multiline then this property just doesn't work. How can I fix this behavior?

Here is illustration:

[image]

XML:

```
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:textColor="#000000"
                  android:focusable="false"
                  android:textSize="16.5dip"
                  android:padding="2dip"
                  android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.1"
                />
```

Comment: Off the top of my head I don't think that's possible without hard-coding the width of your `TextView`.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm having this issue.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you are using parent view (ViewGroup) where you have defined background for your box. You just need to define background for you TextView instead of ViewGroup.
So, do not use background in your ViewGroup, try to use it in the textview. For example:

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:focusable="false"
              android:textSize="16.5dip"
              android:padding="2dip"
              android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.1"
              android:background="@drawable/background_box"
            />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I actually define the background for ViewGroup, but not for TextView. But even if I define a background for the TextView, the result remains the same, the text does not occupy the entire area of ​​the TextView.